# How does one keep a folder expanded in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

I have a folder in Google docs with many subfolders. I want this parent folder to be expanded by default every time I log in to Google docs because I depend a lot on the subfolders.

How do I enable this setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a setting for that; I certainly haven't found it.

However, there is something you can do about it.

If you click on the various folders you'll notice that the URL in the browser's address bar changes. So, every folder is accesible by a certain URL.

If you open a folder that's a direct child of the one you're trying to keep open, you could bookmark it's URL and open Google Docs using that link. It'll always display the parent folder (the one you want) expanded.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that this is not keeping the parent folders expanded out now.  Am I missing something?  Could you attach a few screenshots to demonstrate what you are seeing if it still works?  Right now it always contracts the disclosure arrow even when you go directly to a child folder...

Comment: @ylluminate Yes, it appears it's no longer working. The drive interface changed dramatically since then.